# Unity UI - Applying mask to individual sprites instead of entire texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, sprite, mask

I am trying to apply mask to sprites cut out from a large texture (sprite mode "multiple") that are to be used in the UnityEngine.UI.Image component and so far the results are unsatisfactory.

Here is the shader that I am using, which I copied it off [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/942614/aliasing-when-using-ui-mask.html).

```
Shader "UI/Mask"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MaskTex ("Mask Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

        _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

        _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        { 
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Stencil
        {
            Ref [_Stencil]
            Comp [_StencilComp]
            Pass [_StencilOp] 
            ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest [unity_GUIZTestMode]
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask [_ColorMask]

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;


            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                #ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
                OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw-1.0)*float2(-1,1);
                #endif
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _MaskTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                half4 mask = tex2D(_MaskTex, IN.texcoord);

                color.a *= mask.r;
                clip (color.a - 0.01);
                return color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

I have a strip of texture, which I cut into individual sprites. The following image shows the first two icons, stored in the same PNG.

[image: Icons put inside a main texture]

And next, I follow the instructions on the answer of the [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/942614/aliasing-when-using-ui-mask.html) and prepared a mask PNG, which is simply a black bordered circle with 128 pixels in radius.

[image: circle-256.png]

The material is then prepared...

[image: Material prepared]

and applied.

[image: Material applied]

And here is what I've got:

[image]

I regret that I have no knowledge about shaders so I don't know if I'm describing the problem properly... but apparently, the circle mask is squashed/stretched and applied to the long strip of texture, rather than applied to the individual icons that are cut out.

In other words, the full strip looks like this:

[image: Full strip]

But Unity is doing this:

[image: Imaginary effect of what Unity's doing]

And then it cuts out each icon from the incorrectly masked texture for me to use.

What can be done to the shader to make it mask properly? So I should be seeing something like this:

[image: Desired effect]

Or there is no simple way as this is how materials are supposed to work so I have to give Unity separate textures instead of storing all icons in one long strip?

Comment: Try ticking the preserve aspect. This will keep the circle as circle. You will probably have to fix the size and position of it. It also looks like you are using the same mask for both items since teacher seems to get the edge while students gets more of the center part. You need two instances of the mask.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but preserve aspect doesn't seem to work. Perhaps my elaboration wasn't clear enough. I have added two more images to elaborate the problem. That should explain why the teacher button gets the edge while the student button gets more of the center part. And do you mean I need N Material instances in my Unity project for each of N icons that I use?

Comment: What it looks like is that you have your buttons under one main object and that object has the mask. The hierarchy you need is one main object then under you have N mask objects each with a mask component and Image with preserve aspect then under each of those you have your N objects with teacher/Students and so on. Each mask will cover its own child object.

Comment: Oh. I'm afraid you've misunderstood. I am not using the UI mask system, as it has aliasing problems (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/942614/aliasing-when-using-ui-mask.html) that are not yet fixed. That's why I am resorting to using shaders to mask sprites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's a kind of jury-rigged solution.
Firstly, the circle image that you're using for your mask will need to have its texture wrap mode set to Repeat.

Then, find this line of code:

```
half4 mask = tex2D(_MaskTex, IN.texcoord);
```

And insert this line of code before it:

```
IN.texcoord.x *= 9;
half4 mask = tex2D(_MaskTex, IN.texcoord);
```

This will turn your one circle stretched over 9 sprites into 9 circles repeated over 9 sprites. (If you had more than 9 sprites, you would need to change this.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works. And for my case it is
    IN.texcoord.x *= 10;
    IN.texcoord.y *= 2;
... since I have 10 icons per row and I have 2 rows.

While it definitely works, this mask can only serve this particular 2 x 10 icon map and will draw funny shapes if used on anything else.